# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'multipleSelect'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have used the ajax function when calling this function with multipleSelect like this.
suppose that I have a function that called again in ajax load page

I have included jquery and jquery.multiselect.js include file also

```
$('#demo3').multipleSelect({
                   placeholder: "Select Country",
                   filter:true

});
$("#button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"http:localhost/mydata",
        success:function(data){
           $('#demo4').multipleSelect({
               placeholder: "Select Country",
               filter:true
           });
        },
    });

});
```

demo3 has successfully generate multiselect function. But when I have pressed button the code in **demo4** has error that multiselect function has not been registered in a page?

The error code said..
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'multipleSelect'`

How I can solve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `multiSelect` unless you have defined your own jquery plugin function or used another plugin for `multipleSelect`

```
$('#demo3').multiSelect({
       placeholder: "Select Country",
       filter:true
  });
```

and there is an extra `});` after this. Not sure if you need that.

Comment: Sory I just wrong while writing the code in the previous editing. And I have repaired this and the problems is still the error I have described? Do you have an idea to solve that?

Comment: @mrhands which plugin you are using? can you provide a link to it..?

Comment: @mrhands Doesn't seem to be an issue Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/8VtYL/ Can you replicate the same here.

Comment: @mrhands also try define the demo4 object prior and see if it happens, check the code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C4ut3/